# How can I get Visual Studio to automatically attach debugger to web Site not Application?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2017, iis-10

I have a web application required to run as a Web Site (root application). This is due to it being a multi tenant application that uses the urls sub domain prefix to know which client is accessing it. I create the site in IIS 10 setting the physical path to my Visual Studio 2017 .NET 4.5 MVC application and the site works fine.

I open the web project properties and under Servers choose Local IIS setting and set Project Url to the site I just created in IIS.  Visual Studio then forces me to create a Virtual Directory for the Project Url, to save it, which then creates a Web Application under the default web site. You can't set and save the Project Url without being forced to create the virtual directory.

Now when I start debugging Visual Studio attaches to the Web Application not my web site so my breakpoints never get hit. If I manually attach to the w3wp process where the web site is running I can debug. I had this all working fine prior to recently switching to Git causing me to reconfigure things and I can't recall what I did to make it work.

How can I set the Project Url on web properties page without being forced to create a virtual directory? Or how do I make VS automatically attach to the Web Site and not Web App I was forced to create?

Comment: For the breakpoints never get hit, may I ask where did you put the breakpoints? In C# code or JavaScript?

Comment: C# is all I have, the breakpoints show as normal red circles, they don't turn to white centers after starting the app. I now see that VS is attaching to the the Project Url Web Application w3wp process that it forced me to make to use IIS. It does not attach to the 'Start Url' which is the root Web Site I cretaed fro the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that setting the Servers 'Project Url' in the web projects properties page to 'http://localhost/' does not force you to use the 'Create Virtual Directory' to save the changes. You can't even change the default port here without being forced to create a virtual directory.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! You could mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

This blog might help: [How to Debug Your ASP.NET Projects Running Under IIS](http://codetunnel.io/how-to-debug-your-aspnet-projects-running-under-iis/)

If your project is a website and not a web app, then here are the steps to configure it to use IIS when debugging. This assumes you already have IIS set up and hosting your project.

1. In the solution explorer.
2. Right-click on your project node and navigate to "**Property Pages**".
3. Navigate to "**Start Options**" item in the left pane.
4. In the "**Server**" section make sure "**Use custom server**" is checked.
5. In the "Base URL:" field put in the address you have mapped to your project. (Usually the address you put in your hosts file)

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please state the main points here on SO and [use the link only as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I had read this but since it was quite old didn't attempt it, I did try and discover it didn't help.